# Transport Data from View Controllers in Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

So I started working on a basic app and ran into an issue. The user is taken to a first view controller where they are asked to enter two team names and then press the start button (which performs a segue to the second view controller). On the second view controller are two labels (named homeIdentifier and awayIdentifier ) and I want the labels on the second view controller to update to the names the user put in on the first. I thought it would be simple, but have run into an issue; it says "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)" It also says in red "Thread 1 EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP subcode=0x0)"

How do I do this? The start button is set to perform a segue to the second view controller already, so I don't know if something is going wrong with that process. I've tried the suggestions I've seen here but doesn't seem to work (I don't know if it's because I'm using swift 2, or because I'm transporting 2 variables, etc).

Comment: You have not shown any code and since there are many resources for answering this question, people will down vote you. Anyways, are all of your @IBOutlets properly linked?

Comment: Maybe your problem were that you were assessing to the label's secondViewController from the segue, but it wasn't loaded yet. For that you need to use the intermediate variables, like the example answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think transporting two `variables` is the problem. Just make sure that you only perform the segue of there is two variables and one of them does not equal nil. Make sure to also create two variables in the second `view controller` as you will need to transfer the data over from your first `view controller` into those variables in the second `view controller`. To pass data in swift 2 I would use the `prepare for segue method`. You will also have to set and ID in the attributed inspector for the segue that takes you from the first `view controller` to the second `view controller`.

this goes in the first view controller .swift file

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "segueIdentifier") {
      // make an instance of the second view controller
      var detailVC = segue!.destinationViewController as DetailViewController;
      detailVC.variable1 = "\(firstViewControllerVariable)"
      detailVC.variable2 = "\(secondViewControllerVariable)"
    }
}
```

this is what your second view controller .swift file should consist of

also make sure all your outlets are linked correctly

import UIKit

class secondViewController: UIViewController {

```
var variable1: String = String()
var variable2: String = String()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    homeIdentifier.text = variable1
    awayIdentifier.text = variable2        

}
```

}

hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! Was doing weird things initially, found I needed to add .text to the first/secondViewControllerVariable(s). My first time using stackoverflow, what a help

Answer (score 0):

FirstVC

```
let sc=self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondVC")as! SecondVC

sc.str1="Pass Text"

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(sc, animated:true)
```

SecondVC

```
class ViewDetails: UIViewController 
{

     var str1:String!
     override func viewDidLoad() 
     {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(str1)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
      }

}
```